# pass list as url encoded data httpwebrequest post method

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I want to pass List as @RequestParam from C#. I am using HttpWebRequest. The API to which I am sending request is expecting List as activies in request parameter. HttpMethod for that api is POST.

How to send List acitivities as request parameter?

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(BASE_URL + "/sessions/" + data.Id + "/activities) as HttpWebRequest;
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
```

I am using C# with .net 3.5

do let me know if you want any more info.

Comment: Not sure I have understood the question correctly but could you not just loop through each item in the activities list and build a string with a delimiter between each list item IE activities[1] + "," + activities[2] and then send this in the url and then split the string on the other side, also if there is any sensitive information you could then encode this in to a base64 string

Comment: You'd probably want to send it as JSON? Hard to say without knowing what the API you're working with is asking for, but accepting JSON is pretty standard, and a lot easier to serialize to a list

Comment: @Jedediah and Jogk222 I have updated my question. Yes I want to send as json but I am not sure how to do it.